# Webpack : Could not load file starting with ".". Is there a way to load a file like ".gitignore" into the module?

Tags: webpack-4, webpack-file-loader

```
{
    test: /\.gitignore$/,
    use: [
       'file-loader',
    ]
}
```

is not working...

Webpack ignores .gitignore files and doesn't find them.

i want to use for like this.

```
const module = await import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ `${path}`);
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10282

Comment: Done. not issue